# Several colors in one bar

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to create chart something like this one

[image: Chart with projections]


using chartjs library

Thanks

Comment: You want different color for each bar? or different color in the same bar? Both can be possibel.

Comment: Different color in the same bar

Comment: So you can use a stacked bar chart.

Comment: No. As you can see there are two datasets and three charts. For one datasets it should be two set of data. It's not a stacked bars.

Comment: You can divide the multiple value datasets to single different datasets and put 0 when no value. I have done stacked chart like this before which was containing single to four different data for one bar. sometimes there was only one data, and sometime two, three or four. I put 0 if a dataset has no value.